# the locus of $z$ in the complex plane

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Describe the locus of $z$ in the complex plane if $z$ satisfies:

$$ arg(z)=arg(z+3+i)\quad (mod\ 2\pi) $$

Indeed
Let $O$ be the origin and $B=-3-i$.

\begin{align*}
arg(z)&=arg(z+3+i)\quad  (mod\ 2\pi)\\
arg(z)-arg(z+3+i)&=0\quad  (mod\ 2\pi)\\
arg\left(\dfrac{z}{z-(-3-i)}\right)&=0\quad (mod\ 2\pi)\\
(\vec{BM},\vec{OM})&=0\quad (mod\ 2\pi)
\end{align*}
then $(\vec{BM},\vec{OM})=0\quad (mod\ 2\pi)$ can be represent Ray 0B without point O and B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $O$ be the origin and $B=-3-i$.

Draw the line $OB$ extended in both directions, and erase the section between $O$ and $B$.

Now all the points on the two part lines, not including $O$ and $B$ themselves, satisfy the given condition.

This is quite easily seen if you just draw a picture. Alternatively you can arrive at it algebraically by setting $z=x+iy$ and using the condition that $\arg\frac{z}{z+3+i}=0$

This condition means that $$Re(\frac{z}{z+3+i})>0$$ and $$Im(\frac{z}{z+3+i})=0$$
So we have $$ \frac{z}{z+3+i}=\frac{x+iy}{(x+3)+i(y+1)}$$
$$=\frac{x+iy}{(x+3)+i(y+1)}\times\frac{(x+3)-i(y+1)}{(x+3)-i(y+1)}$$
This leads to the relation $$y=\frac 13x$$ together with the condition $$x(x+3)+y(y+1)>0$$
This is equivalent to saying that the locus is the line $OB$, but only those points lying outside the circle whose diameter is $OB$

Comment: yes i want to arrive to that algebraiically and i already got $\arg\frac{z}{z+3+i}=0$ but i 'm stuck here

Comment: See my amended answer...do you want me to fill in the details?

Comment: yes if u could i'll be gratfull

Comment: @DavidQuinn. Nicely explained as usual. +1

Comment: @Shailesh...many thanks once again!

Comment: +1 from me too that was good explanation and i understand but u can feel free to add more details for the Audience Futures.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $z=x+iy$

If $\implies $arg$(z)=\arctan \dfrac yx=\phi$(say) $\implies\tan\phi=\dfrac yx$

Similarly, arg$(z+3+i)=\arctan\dfrac{y+1}{x+3}=\psi$(say) $\implies\tan\psi=\dfrac{y+1}{x+3}$

But $\phi\equiv \psi\pmod{2\pi}\implies\tan\phi=\tan\psi$

Hope you can take it from here!

Comment: i still can't see if u could details more

Comment: @Educ, What  can you get from $\tan\phi=\tan\psi$?

Comment: sorry but i don't know